# Passing values to forms

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a form, that I'd like to display a select list, where the user can select an item and save.

What I need to do though, is pass a value to the form:

```
$form = new TestForm($id)
```

How do I then get the value of `$id` in my `Testform` class?

Comment: What's inside this `$id`? The default value of the list? An id to retrieve something? What do you want to with it?

Comment: Well the `$id` is a value i want to pass to the form widget via the `query` option in `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice`

Comment: Ok, so looking around: `$id = $this->getOption('id');` and `TestForm(array(),array('id'=>$id))`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seemed to work:

```
$id = $this->getOption('id');
```

and

```
TestForm(array(),array('id'=>$id))
```